# .Net TCP vs WCF vs Powershell

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, powershell

This has been asked a lot, but I'm after more specific answers.

I'm designing/developing a suite of applications that are dependent on communicating with a agent and a manager. They will be communicating commands (from manager to agent) and statistics (agent to manager). At the moment, this suite of applications will only run on the Windows platform, but eventually should scale out to other systems. Some places where this application would be used might not want to install a great load of applications across their systems, and some might not want the manager side sitting there sucking up juice (analysis!) and therefore might want it in the cloud.

So, I know that I can use .Net TCP sockets, which seems to have good raw performance and allows me a great deal of flexibility.

I also know that I could use Windows Communication Foundation, which seems like naturally a better choice.

But, seeing as I'm sending commands and receiving statistics, I could just use Powershell to connect remotely and use the plethora of commands available from what would be the server, ruling out writing a client application full stop.

Bearing in mind that these applications (client especially) should just sit there, be quiet, do their job and not interfere with general operations, which would you suggest to be better?

If you need more clarification I'll be happy to do so!

Thanks.

Comment: If you can script it up with powershell or similar and not affect the end-user, that's the path I would take. Simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you discribe your application, I would reformulate it as an 'agent' located on clients and a manager located on the server. If it's so the manager sends commands to the agents and the agents respond or store statics available to the manager.

For such an architecture you can imagine using **WMI**, with a WMI provider on the agent, and wathever you want on the server. Powershell can be used on the server to query your agent. In the near future you can use the same architecture puting your agent on a Linux box with NanoWBEM on the top of WS-Man Protocol (see [Standards-based Management in Windows Server “8”](http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowsserver/archive/2012/03/30/standards-based-management-in-windows-server-8.aspx)) .

Comment: Oop, thanks! That's what I wanted to say, but I guess the coffee hadn't kicked in.
I will investigate NanoWBEM. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> They will be communicating commands (from server to client) and
>   statistics (client to server). At the moment, this suite of
>   applications will only run on the Windows platform, but eventually
>   should scale out to other systems.

In your description there is one requirement that is not compatible with Power Shell.
Power Shell works only in Windows world.

WCF service should not consume any resources if they are properly configured. IIS and WAS are able to load services on-demand (upon getting request from client) and unload when it is not necessary.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/blambert/archive/2009/02/13/enable-iis.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731053.aspx

TCP sockets are the best from performance point of view but unfortunately implementation will require lots of extra DEV and QA work to implement all plumbing that already exists in WCF. When you finish that work you will have one more "bicycle" that is not compatible with industry standards.

**My vote is WCF.**

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. I would have to investigate windows-!windows management. Thanks for the links. Very useful :)